# Should I run my EC2 instance 24/7 if I do not know when the endpoint will be hit?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am making an ios app and using an EC2 instance to host my backend code (in Django). Even though I only have a few users (less than 10), I do not know when they will be using the app throughout each day.

Do I need to run my EC2 instance 24/7 in order to accept api calls at any moment? Wouldn't that be very expensive for the actual amount of compute time I need to be handled?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the your backend is deployed on an EC2 instance and the EC2 instance is not running, your code will not be executed and your API calls can't be handled.

You could implement your backend with [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/features/), which runs serverless and is only charged by usage. There seems to be a tool, [Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa), which lets you deploy Python apps on AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Hakuna Cloud](https://hakuna.cloud), it's a service that can start your EC2 server when an HTTP/S request arrives to a domain and then automatically stop it when no one is calling the server for a while (the default time should be 30 minutes). It does not request any change in your code, you just need to configure the service and change your DNS (it actually works as an HTTPS secure proxy). 
The service for one EC2 instance only cost 1$ per month and it's free for a month.

To configure the service you need to install a CLI:

```
npm install -g @porketta.io/porcli
```

Then run:

```
porcli provider create
```

It will ask you AWS Credentials (Access Key Id and Secret Access Key) that can be generated in the IAM AWS Console. You can create a user with a specific role and permissions as stated [here](https://docs.hakuna.cloud/aws_ec2_provider_configuration.html#aws-policy).

The run:

```
porcli vhost create
```

and follow the instructions. It will show you all your running EC2 instances and let you choose which one you want to configure with Hakuna Cloud. After that, it will ask you to which FQDN the EC2 instance is linked.

When you end this part you have to change your DNS. If you are using Route 53 for DNS you can do it from the AWS Console. you just need to change or create a CNAME Record Set like:

```
 service.yourdomain.com CNAME eu1.lb.hakuna.cloud
```